# How do I use get_dotapp_dir?

Tags: macos, cmake, bundle

How can I use `get_dotapp_dir`?

I'm using cmake 3.6 and the Ninja generator (so not Xcode).

For example, suppose I have fred.c:

```
int main(void){return 0;}
```

And CMakeLists.txt: (the cmake version number is something I am stuck with)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.21.1)
include(BundleUtilities)
add_executable(fred MACOSX_BUNDLE fred.c)
set_target_properties(fred PROPERTIES BUNDLE TRUE)
get_dotapp_dir($<TARGET_FILE:fred> THING)
add_custom_command(TARGET fred POST_BUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo ${THING} VERBATIM)
```

The output when I build is `/Users/worktom/tests/cmake_get_dotapp_dir/build/fred.app/Contents/MacOS/fred`... which is not the bundle folder!

I sort-of expected this, because generator expressions are evaluated at build time, and not when cmake is running. But then... it seems to be sort-of working, because the target file's path has come through! What's going on? Is this supposed to work? When/how am I actually supposed to call `get_dotapp_dir`?

(Having built the bundle, I want to copy additional files into it, and then on every build I want to copy the result into additional folders, none of which are related to the cmake projects I'm building. So it looks like I need the path in a form that can be passed into `cmake -E`, as per my example.)

Comment: Why do you have the output so complicated and not just 'message'?

Comment: In the long run I want to use the bundle path with `cmake -E copy` (and the like). So if I test it with `cmake -E echo`, I know it will work.

Comment: Does it work with `message`?

Comment: Since there's a generator expression involved, I'm assuming not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hitting this problem on a second project last year, I ended up concluding that `get_dotapp_dir` is just useless nowadays, makes little sense with cmake 3+, and is probably just something that's there for backwards compatibility.

If you can upgrade to cmake 3.9, there's a new generator expression that looks just the ticket: [`$<TARGET_BUNDLE_DIR:>`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#informational-expressions). [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45432489/target-bundle-dirtgt-generator-equivalent-for-cmake-3-9).

I haven't upgraded just yet, and I ended up managing to work around this. My project needed to know the bundle folder for two reasons:

1. Asset files that are loaded at runtime and need to be included in the bundle. What I did for this in the end was have the program find its EXE path at runtime, and load assets from folders relative to that path. Then the cmake build can just use `$<TARGET_FILE_DIR:>` to decide where to put the files - somewhere in the bundle folder, but it doesn't matter exactly where.

   This behaviour also makes sense for Windows, so no need for a separate code path.

   Repo links, since this project is open source: [copy files to places relative to EXE path](https://github.com/tom-seddon/b2/blob/e2a6d60782fb705a30163c871aa8222d34f1c89e/src/b2/CMakeLists.txt#L301), [retrieve EXE path at runtime](https://github.com/tom-seddon/b2/blob/e2a6d60782fb705a30163c871aa8222d34f1c89e/src/shared/c/path_osx.cpp#L11).
2. The .icns file that OS X uses to load the icons has to go in the `Resources` folder. This can be arranged by including the file in the target's sources list, and configuring that file's package location property appropriately.

   ```
   target_sources(b2 PRIVATE b2.icns)
   set_source_files_properties(b2.icns PROPERTIES MACOSX_PACKAGE_LOCATION Resources)
   ```

   The executable target needs to have its bundle icon file set up appropriately with something along the lines of `set_target_properties(b2 PROPERTIES MACOSX_BUNDLE_ICON_FILE b2.icns)`.

   Again, repo links: [cmake stuff for OS X icns file](https://github.com/tom-seddon/b2/blob/e2a6d60782fb705a30163c871aa8222d34f1c89e/src/b2/CMakeLists.txt#L99).

Comment: If you look at the cmake stuff for the OS X icns file, you might notice a `set(BUNDLE_CONTENTS_FOLDER $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:b2>/..)` line. This variable is never used, and clearly I never noticed until just now. But anyway, if your EXE is going into the `MacOS` folder, or whatever, this sort of thing might be another way of constructing bundle-relative paths.