# $<TARGET_BUNDLE_DIR:tgt> generator equivalent for cmake < 3.9

Tags: macos, cmake

Since cmake 3.9 the following [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) has been introduced:

```
$<TARGET_BUNDLE_DIR:tgt>
```

For which the documentation states that:

> Full path to the bundle directory (my.app, my.framework, or my.bundle) where tgt is the name of a target.

How can one obtain the same result (path to the bundle directory) if using cmake < 3.9?

---

I tried the following:

```
include(BundleUtilities)
get_dotapp_dir($<TARGET_FILE:my_target> DOTAPP_DIR)
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work. The documentation for `get_dotapp_dir` says:

> Returns the nearest parent dir whose name ends with ”.app” given the full path to an executable. If there is no such parent dir, then simply return the dir containing the executable.

And *the dir containing the executable* is exactly what I'm getting out of it, even if a parent `.app` dir actually exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `$<TARGET_FILE:my_target>` is a generator expression. According to the documentation, it is evaluated at build time (not at CMake generation time). See the related doc (emphasis is mine):

> Generator expressions are evaluated **during build system generation** to
>   produce information specific to each build configuration.
>
> Generator expressions are allowed in the context of many target
>   properties, such as LINK_LIBRARIES, INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES,
>   COMPILE_DEFINITIONS and others. They may also be used when using
>   commands to populate those properties, such as
>   target_link_libraries(), target_include_directories(),
>   target_compile_definitions() and others.

In other words, you cannot use `$<TARGET_FILE:my_target>` as argument to `get_dotapp_dir`. You have to pass a variable containing the full path of your executable.

Since CMake 3, the full path of generated target is impossible to retrieve without this generator expression. See [CMP0026](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/policy/CMP0026.html) for more info.

So as long as you keep this Policy set to its default value, you will not be able to compute the full path to your executable or the parent bundle.

[You are not the first](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39618753/1887976) trying to solve this issue. But depending on "what to do with this bundle path", you may try the following solutions:

1. Set CMP0026 to `OLD`, and use LOCATION property to get the path to your executable, and the give this path to `get_dotapp_dir` to retrieve the corresponding bundle path. This solution is definitely not portable, may stop to work in the future, and is not advised...
2. If you need to access to your bundle path from a custom command or a custom target (at build time), you may use a script (python, php, bash, perl, etc.) to compute the path to bundle from the path to executable.

Currently, we use something like this in some project:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET MyTarget POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${PYTHON_EXECUTABLE} -u MakeRelease.py $<TARGET_FILE:MyTarget>
)
```

Unfortunately, there is no clean way to retrieve the bundle path at configuration time at the moment...

Comment: So, `LOCATION` is bound to the `.app` directory when the target is a bundle? I didn't try it actually for I guessed it returned the path of the executable within the bundle.

Comment: If your target has property BUNDLE set to "true", the executable is built under a path like: "<target_output_dir>/MyTarget.app/Contents/MyTarget"

Comment: The target is marked as `MACOSX_BUNDLE` when `add_executable` is called. I know where it is built, what I'm asking is if `LOCATION` property for such a target contains the path of the executable or the path of the bundle, for `$<TARGET_FILE:my_target>` contains the one of the executable.

Comment: LOCATION contains the path to the executable. But since it is resolved at configuration time, you will be able to use the value of this property as argument to "get_dotapp_dir"

Comment: Oh, ok, it's not clear from the answer, sorry. Could you mention it explicitly in the answer? I mean, the fact that one should combine `LOCATION` **and** `get_dotapp_dir`.  It will help future readers. Thank you.

Comment: Actually, i just tried and it appear LOCATION property is no longer readable